# Ajax and PHP login system does not respond if the login was successful

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to make a login system with PHP and Ajax, and for some reason, the code is not responding as needed. I already have a functioning sign up form, and I tried using as much of the sign-up form code as possible to try to fix the bug; however, the code still does not function properly.

HTML:

```
    <div id="loginOutput"></div>
    <table class="login">
     <tr>
      <th><p>Username</p></th>
      <th><input type="text" id="username"></th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <th><p>Password</p></th>
      <th><input type="password" id="password"></th>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Log In" id="submit">
```

Ajax:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#submit").click(function () {
      var username = $("#username").val();
      var password = $("#password").val();
      var data = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
      $.ajax({
       method: "post",
       url: "login.php?",
       data: data,
       success: function (data) {
       $("#loginOutput").html(data);
       }
      });
     });
    });
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
     $username = "";
     $password = "";
     $errors = array();
     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];
     $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost:8889", "Daniel Borovskiy", "password", "suicidalKauze");
     if (!$connect) {
      die("Connection failed" . mysqli_connect_error());
     }
     if (empty($username)) {
      array_push($errors, "Please enter your username.");
     }
     if (empty($password)) {
      array_push($errors, "Please enter your password.");
     }
     if (count($errors) > 0) {
      foreach ($errors as $error) {
       echo "<p style='color: red; text-align: center;'>".$error."</p>";
      }
     }
     if (count($errors) == 0) {
      $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'");
      $amount = mysqli_num_rows($query);
      if ($amount == 1){
       session_start();
       $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
       $_SESSION['firstName'] = $row['firstName'];
       echo $_SESSION['firstName'];
      } else {
       echo "Your username and password do not match.";
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: Your code is dangerously vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Are there any errors in the web console?

Comment: You shouldn't store passwords in plain text, use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.

Comment: does your code show any error ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using POST method, you can simple use (why **?** mark in url)

```
   $.ajax({
       method: "post",
       url: "login.php",
       data: {username:username,password:password},
       success: function (data) {
       $("#loginOutput").html(data);
       }
      });
```

You should be able to get your data using `$_POST['username']`

Thanks

Comment: I tried changing the data passage code to what you suggested; unfortunately, there is still nothing being outputted by the Ajax (and PHP.)